# knockout.js and rendering tables

Tags: knockout.js, html-table

Is it possible to render the same thing below without the containerless control flow syntax and have valid html?

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: dates">
        <tr>
            <td class="empty"></td>
            <td class="date-container" data-bind="attr: { colspan: $parent.gymCourts().length }">
                <div class="date" data-bind="html: date"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <!-- ko foreach: times -->
        <tr class="time-games">
            <td class="time-container">
                <div class="time" data-bind="html: time"></div>
            </td>
            <!-- ko foreach: games -->
            <td class="game-container">
                <div class="game">
                    <span data-bind="html: awayTeam.name"></span> vs. <span data-bind="html: homeTeam.name"></span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <!-- /ko -->
        </tr>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </tbody>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place multiple `tbody` elements in a table, so if you are able to place your `foreach` on the `table` element, then you can do:

```
​<table data-bind="foreach: dates">
   <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td data-bind="html: date">

        </td>
   </tr>
   <tbody data-bind="foreach: times">
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td data-bind="html: time">

            </td>
        </tr>       
    </tbody>
</table>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: mmm that might work Ill give it a go.  I knew about tbody, but didnt think about using tr and tbody in sequence.

Comment: I believe that would of worked, but I have a little more to the html from the parent that I should of included.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, but if you used `<div>` tags in "table mode" I think you could:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: dates">
    <div style="display: table-row">
        <div style="display: table-cell"></div>
        <div style="display: table-cell" data-bind="html: date"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div data-bind="foreach: times">
    <div style="display: table-row">
        <div style="display: table-cell"></div>
        <div style="display: table-cell" data-bind="html: time"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```